# How do I perform server side paging in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to be able to select a certain range of rows from a table using SQL.

What TSQL command should I use to perform server side paging?

I am no taking about server side paging?
I want to select first 10 rows from a table and the do some calculation

```
cmd.commandText :="select top 10 from table "
ada.fill(dt)
for each(datarow dtr in dt.rows)
{
//calulation
}
```

then I want to select next 10 rows and same repeat until the end of table

Comment: there is no id field  in table

Comment: Take a look on Top and Skip keywords...

Comment: So this is actually about *batches* not paging. You may want to consider to perform this kind of processing inside SQL Server directly instead of fetching data into your app. Take into account that rows you fetched could have changed while where processing them in your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft introduced ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Server 2005 to help with paging...

```
SELECT * FROM (     
  SELECT          
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY City) AS row, *  
  FROM Cities  
) AS a WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Use a variable for 1 and 10 to dynamically get the next set.

```
create proc dbo.whatever_select_paging
  @int page
as

SELECT * FROM (     
  SELECT          
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY City) AS row, *  
  FROM Cities  
) AS a WHERE row BETWEEN ((@page-1) * 10) +1 AND (@page * 10)-1

go
```

Comment: no what happend my question changed ? who changed admin?

Comment: @eldhose - Josh edited it because it was unclear. He does seem to have removed all mention of `C#` or the fact that you want to do this to process 2 million rows in his revision though. What exactly are you doing that you need to process 2 million rows in batches of 10 using `C#`?

Comment: no just example i told 10 in my table 220000 rows there i want to process these all data in a loop

Comment: Regardless... you still want SQL paging.  Keep track of which page you're on in C#, keep processing until the record count is less than 10.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - This could be very inefficient for processing higher batches. If the OP shares their table structure and reason for doing this there may be better ways.

Comment: @MartinSmith - batch processing generally is inefficient and usually performed without a UI (or at least without someone waiting for results).  I'm simply answering the question "How do I perform server side paging in SQL Server 2005".  Had the question been "How could I process 200,000 rows of data efficiently?", I'm guessing we would have more details and my answer would be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ROW_NUMBER to accomplish this. Look at the [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/11/sql-server-2005-t-sql-paging-query-technique-comparison-over-and-row_number-cte-vs-derived-table/) for ROW_NUMBER usage on paging.

Comment: i saw this before but i dont know how can do it in c#

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 20 FROM MyData
WHERE orderNum <= 61
ORDER BY orderNum DESC
```

This will get 20 rows starting from row 61 through to row 80 (can get more than 20 if you have duplicated orderNum values)